# 'ascii' codec can't encode characters while uploading file in django and cpanel

Tags: django, apache, django-models, file-upload, cpanel

hello I have a Django project. it work perfectly in local host but when I deployed it on cPanel I got an error when I want to upload an image.

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 37-43: ordinal not in range(128)

/home/monkeymo/virtualenv/django/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/storage/filesystem.py, line 106, in _save
```

can you help me about this?